# Predicting OutOfMemoryError in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory

Consider the following Java class:

```
public class Mem {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        printMem();
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[Integer.parseInt(args[0])];
        printMem();
    }

    private static void printMem() {
        System.gc();
        final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final long free = runtime.freeMemory();
        final long total = runtime.totalMemory();
        final long used = total - free;
        final long max = runtime.maxMemory();
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Free: %,d; Used: %,d; Total: %,d; Max: %,d",
                free, used, total, max));
    }
}
```

And here is the output for two different sizes of the byte array:

```
$ java -Xmx1g Mem 700000000
Free: 250,063,176; Used: 1,595,064; Total: 251,658,240; Max: 954,728,448
Free: 92,445,200; Used: 700,278,256; Total: 792,723,456; Max: 954,728,448

$ java -Xmx1g Mem 800000000
Free: 250,063,176; Used: 1,595,064; Total: 251,658,240; Max: 954,728,448
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Maximum available memory is about 950 MB. I can allocate a 700 MB array but not an 800 MB array.
I guess that the heap space corresponds to vast majority of that 950 MB but I cannot allocate an 800 MB array because the free space on the heap need not be continuous.

In a more complex application with max memory 7.5 GB, I get OutOfMemoryError when allocation a 500 MB array despite the fact that just 2 GB are used.

Is there a way to predict that a particular memory allocation will cause an OutOfMemoryError before it happens?

**UPDATE**
The question has been just marked as duplicate to [Check if there is enough memory before allocating byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534063/check-if-there-is-enough-memory-before-allocating-byte-array). However, there are significant differences in these two questions.

- Wrapping the allocation into a try-catch block is not an option for me. I do not control the allocation. I can just write something like a plugin to an existing Java application.
- I cannot avoid allocation of large objects.
- The referred question suggests calling `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` but the sample in my question shows that the result of such call is extremely unreliable. First, the application can get much more memory if `total < max`. Second, the allocation can fail even if there seems to be much more free memory than I allocate.